# Combinatorial proof for $\binom{2n}{2} = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I completely understand the algebra behind this, but I'm having trouble writing a worded combinatorial proof to show $\binom{2n}{2} = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$

Can anyone at least hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588561/showing-that-2n-choose-2-2-n-choose-2-n2-by-combinatorial-and-algeb/588651#588651

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Divide the set of $2n$ elements into two sets of $n$ each (say $A$ and $B$). Then selecting $2$ elements from the original set is equivalent to one of the following:

1. Select $2$ elements from $A$ or
2. Select $2$ elements from $B$ or
3. Select an element from $A$ and one from $B$.

Comment: Does $n^2$ arises from Step 3, perhaps? Could you elaborate a little bit more on this step, please?